# Why is System.err.println is printed before then System.out.println?

Tags: java

I was tryingout Logger example from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) chain of responsibility article. 
running the example in idea it prints:

```
Sending to stderr: An error has occurred.
Writing to stdout: Entering function y.
Writing to stdout: Step1 completed.
Sending via email: Step1 completed.
Writing to stdout: An error has occurred.
Sending via email: An error has occurred.
```

but when i put a break point in stderrs writeMessage

```
class StderrLogger extends Logger {
    public StderrLogger(int mask) {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    protected void writeMessage(String msg) {
        System.err.println("Sending to stderr: " + msg);//break out here
    }
}
```

it prints all the messags except std err, there is no threads involved here, 
then why its printing stderr at first line in run case?.

Comment: Streams can be buffered differently, flushed differently, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.err` flushes differently from `System.out` in Eclipse.

Try this in Eclipse:

```
public class Derp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("OUT");
            System.err.println("ERR");
        }
    }
}
```

This will randomly print out most of the `OUT`s and most of the `ERR`s in big chunks. However, this is an Eclipse issue, not a Java issue, as pointed out by Evgeniy Dorofeev.

If you run this sample program in a terminal, you will notice the correct output, without any flushing needed.

Update:
Thanks to Evgeniy Dorofeev for pointing this out! 
The flushing not working is an Eclipse problem!

Comment: In Idea community edition 11.1 it prints all the err first and then out.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` -> Sends the output to a standard output stream. Generally monitor.

`System.err.println` -> Sends the output to a standard error stream. Generally monitor.

The streams `out` and `err` are independent.

To get the desired output you must flush the streams or just use just one stream for all outputting.

You can use `System.out.flush();` and `System.err.flush();` in your code

Comment: if i change the class @Andrei suggested to : 

System.out.println("OUT");
System.out.flush();
System.err.println("ERR");
System.err.flush();

it prints all the OUT first and then ERR.

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing it from Eclipse, it is a known bug  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205

Comment: This is the correct answer. Running a similar program from the command line and outputting to the OS terminal produces the right output.